# How to add third level of category menu in dotLiquid

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, dotliquid

I am working in Comarch E-sklep program made by Comarch where I am using dotLiquid language to modify shop template. I need help to show 3rd level of categories. Standard dotLiquid script allows you to get only two levels of menu. In documentation I read that I need to input special javascript code but I don't know how to put it corectly. Because I already started to learn js and don't understand all things.

```html
<h2>Menu</h2>
{% assign groupNodes = page.GroupNodes %}
<ul>
  {% for menuTreeOne in groupNodes -%}
    <li><a href="{{ menuTreeOne.Url }}">{{ menuTreeOne.Name }}</a>
      {% if menuTreeOne.Nodes -%}
      <span style="color: lightblue;"> yes </span><br>
          
          <ul>
          {% for menuTreeTwo in menuTreeOne.Nodes -%}
          <li><a href="{{ menuTreeTwo.Url }}">{{ menuTreeTwo.Name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor -%}
          </ul>
  
      {% else %}
      <span style="color: red;"> nope </span>
      {% endif -%}
  </li>
{% endfor -%}
 </ul>
```

Fragment from documentation:

> Action GET
>
> This action allows you to download data from the server to create, for
>   example: breadcrumbs or menu.
>
> Get/Groups
>
> Gets the subgroups for the specified group. This action allows you to
>   build a dynamic menu or breadcrumbs.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 (function () {
 $(function () {
 $('nav.breadcrumbs>ol>li').hover( 
 function () { 
 var t = $(this), gId = ('' + t.data('id')).split(',')[1]; 
 if (gId && t.find('ol').length == 0) { 
 $.get(null, { __action: 'Get/Groups', groupId: gId, languageId: __lngId }, function (d) { 
 var obj = d.action.Object; 
 if (obj.length) { 
 var ol = $('<ol></ol>'); 
 t.append(ol); 
 $.each(obj, function (i, el) { 
 var a = $('<a></a>').attr('href', el.Url).text(el.Title); 
 ol.append(a); 
 a.wrap('<li></li>') 
});
}
});
}
 else t.find('ol').show(); 
},
 function () { 
 $(this).find('ol').hide(); 
}
);
});
 })(jQuery); 
</script>
```